# Advantages of using Tabs over Intent

Tags: android

I just found out that we can use `overridePendingTransition(0,0)` to make a very simple transition between Layouts that override the current Android transition.

```
switch(v.getId()){  
    case R.id.btnCorner:
        Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Settings.class);
        startActivity(i);       
        overridePendingTransition(0,0);
        break;
}
```

What is the advantage of using tabs over such a simple procedure?

My opinion is that tabs facilitate the transmission of variables between one "window screen" to another. Rather than passing the variable through intents.

Please note that I am not familiar with using `Tabs` and I hope someone can clarify the idea of using Tabs in an application.

Comment: Go and get some info here :-http://www.androidhive.info/2011/08/android-tab-layout-tutorial/

Comment: I've seen this tutorial before, but since you mentioned it again, i'll re-give it a look. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Jonathan Hugh, nice questions really helpful for users , here i am going to give you brief description for both like : Intent take an example of any **master-detail** form where we want by using click on any `ListView` item row need to **call** another `activity` in this case i recommend you to use Intent because in same flow you require your result to be done, and other side, using `tab` it will give you more **convenience** to put your wishlist features in app using separate-separate tabs for all....

Tabs Like:-

```
private void setTabs()
{
    addTab("Tab1", R.drawable.tab1, tab1.class);
    addTab("Tab2", R.drawable.tab2, tab2.class);

    addTab("Tab3", R.drawable.tab3, tab3.class);
    addTab("Tab4", R.drawable.tab4, tab4.class);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What do you meen under `tabs`? There are several ways in Android to implement Tabs pattern. Some of them are better, other are not very good or deprecated. Not all of them are :

> facilitate the transmission of variables

For example, using 3 different `Activity`, will significatelly increase amount of code, increase code connectivity and decrease code quality.

Comment: `Tabs`, When you open Google Chrome, and you intend to you navigate to many urls, you open many tabs by clicking CTRL+T. This is what I mean by Tabs. However, what i mean by `Intent`, is whenever you want to navigate to a certain URL, you open Google Chrome each time, in other words, you use one tab in each instance.

Answer (score 0):

According to my point of view, in tabs, you can organize your work more systemically as compare to Intent.